# Facebook Share can I add Alt text for flash videos?

Tags: iphone, android, flash, facebook, facebook-sharer

You know with Facebook, how you can share video on your sites and Facebook embeds the videos via flash.

Well on computers and laptop the embeded video will play on Facebook since they have Flash installed. But for iPhone and Android users will just be redirected to the site, I want to stop this and add an alt text stated something like "Flash is needed to view", is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

With HTML you can just do that with something like this:

```
<p>
  <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif"  alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
  </a>
</p>
```

But I have no Idea if that is possible or not with the mobile phones.

Comment: For flash videos, someone use `<a href="xxx" alt="test flash"><object></object></a>`